# Swift: how to use UISwitch to control UITextField to be enabled or disabled with a delegate

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, uiswitch, uitextfielddelegate

In `XCode 6.3.2`, I have a UITextField:

```
@IBOutlet weak var uiswitchControlledTextField: UITextField!
```

I am now using a UISwitch (named `mySwitch`) to control its enabled or disabled state in the following way:

```
@IBOutlet weak var mySwitch: UISwitch!
mySwitch.addTarget(self, action: Selector("stateChanged:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

//callback below:
func stateChanged(switchState: UISwitch) {
        uiswitchControlledTextField.enabled = switchState.on

    }
```

The above works well, however, I am looking to try if it would be possible to create a UITextFieldDelegate to control the above UITextField in the same way. So far, I have the following by implementing `textFieldShouldBeginEditing`, in which I wish to return false to disable the UITextField, but I don't know how to let the `UISwitch` dynamically return **true** or **false** from `textFieldShouldBeginEditing`

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class SwitchControlledTextFieldDelegate: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {

    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        return false; //do not show keyboard or cursor
    }

}
```

In ViewController, I try to set

```
self.uiswitchControlledTextField.delegate = SwitchControlledTextFieldDelegate()
```

but it does not work as I wished. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.uiswitchControlledTextField.delegate = SwitchControlledTextFieldDelegate()
```

The problem is that that line merely creates an instance of your SwitchControlledTextFieldDelegate class, which then immediately goes right back out of existence.

You need to use, as your text field delegate, some instance which already exists and which will persist - like, perhaps, your view controller!

Comment: thanks, points taken. But when the UI Switch is off, how can enable the UITextField? do I re-assign its delegate to something else?

Answer (score 0):

(Xcode 7)
Use this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Setting the delegate
    self.textField3.delegate = self

    self.editingSwitch.setOn(false, animated: false)
} 
// Text Field Delegate Methods
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    return self.editingSwitch.on
}
@IBAction func toggleTheTextEditor(sender: AnyObject) {
    if !(sender as! UISwitch).on {
        self.textField3.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```